# Grails script calling another

Tags: grails

I am trying to write a grails script, which I can use to do several tasks.  Some of these tasks involve calling other scripts.  For examples calls to `grails schema-export` with a few different switches. How do I do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done similar thing for different task, you can use below code to call a dbManager script which internally uses same code to run your other tasks in your case it might be **grails schema-export** based on environment as well.

```
def dbManager =("grails -Dgrails.env="+Environment.currentEnvironment+" run-script scripts/dbManager.groovy").execute()
dbManager.waitForProcessOutput( System.out, System.err )
```